How do I make Tomcat exit with an error code when the root webapp fails on startup?
I found out that when there's an error during startup e.g. ServletContextListener that tomcat simply exits with an error code of 0
How do I change that behaviour without embedding System.exit(1) on my code?

It would help if there was a specific example which reproduces this issue.
